# Implementation of the GMSL seq function

Tags: string, makefile, gnu-make, equality, gmsl

The [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) contains a `seq` function. It compares two strings and returns a boolean value in the form of `$(true)` and `$(false)`, indicating whether they are equal.

It is implemented with the [`subst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) function:

```
seq = $(if $(subst x$1,,x$2)$(subst x$2,,x$1),$(false),$(true))
```

What I would like to understand is:

- Why does it use *two* substitutions to determine whether two strings are equal?
- Why does it prepend a `x` to both strings?

---

It is clearly testing equality by evaluating `x - y = 0`, where:

- The binary `-` operator corresponds to the `subst` function
- The two strings correspond to the `x` and `y` variables
- `0` corresponds to the empty string, which is logically false in Make

`-` is commutative, so `x - y = y - x`.

So, is there a reason this function was implemented evaluating `(x - y) + (y - x) = 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why does it use two substitutions to determine whether two strings are equal?*

To deal with the situation where one string is just the other string repeated. Because `$(subst)` will remove all occurrences of a string `seq` would fail horribly if it were written like this:

```
seq = $(if $(subst $1,,$2),$(false),$(true))
```

when testing the strings `aa` and `aaaa` as `$(subst aa,,aaaa)` would be an empty string which would give the answer `$(false)`, but reverse the strings and `$(subst aaaa,,aa)` would be `aa` which would give the answer true.

So, the substitution is done both ways to ensure that when `$1` is removed from `$2` the result is an empty string and vice versa (I'm using `$(subst)` as a subtraction operator here). Because of the way `$(if)` works the two `$(subst)`s are essentially being ANDed together (empty string == true and so concatenation of strings becomes AND).

*Why does it prepend a `x` to both strings?*

`seq` is implemented as follows:

```
seq = $(__gmsl_tr2)$(if $(subst x$1,,x$2)$(subst x$2,,x$1),$(false),$(true))
```

Unfortunately, my reasoning for having the prepended `x`'s seems to have been lost in the mists of time. I suspect it was related to the fact that GNU make will often strip whitespace and in the case of `$(subst)` whitespace is removed. See the output of

```
$(subst  ,,the quick brown)
```

Note the double space at the start there. Now look at the output of

```
$(subst e, ,the quick brown)
```

In the first case the space was consumed by GNU make and `$(subst)` did nothing. In the second case the space was *not* consumed.

However, in the context in which I am using `$(subst)` this doesn't matter because spaces coming from variables like `$1` are preserved (i.e. space stripping happens before expansion). You can see that with the following:

```
space :=
space +=
$(subst  $(space),,the quick brown)
```

That puts a single space character in `space` and then uses it to removes spaces from `the quick brown`.

So, I believe that the `x`s are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Watch what happens if you only compare once

```
seq = $(if $(subst x$1,,x$2),false,true)
$(error $(call seq,,xxxxxx))
```

Makefile:2: *** true.  Stop.

Oops.

Comment: Yes, but why? Also, why prepend a character?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira My guess is there's some combination of input, perhaps whitespace or `$`s, that needs to be escaped, I haven't found anything yet though.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira I ran the `gsml-tests` file but all of `seq` tests succeed even without `x`, I'm beginning to think it's an artefact of a possible earlier implementation of `seq` that didn't call `subst` twice.